# Getting hook_menu() to respond to a URN

Tags: routes

I have a site that can respond to [URNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URN).  For example, I need to be able to serve up a response to

```
http://example.com/urn:myscheme:foo:bar:12345
```

So, I need a router item that can match against the "urn" or "urn:myscheme" portion, and get "foo:bar:12345" as the argument (either exploded or not).

Can [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) be configured this way?

I have tried

```
$item['urn'] = array(...);
$item['urn:'] = array(...);
```

without any luck.  I can do this with a [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) trick, but am curious whether it can be done directly.  For the purposes of this question, I can't use path aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Would love to be proven wrong, but I don't think that's easily possible using `hook_menu()`.

Core only considers `/` as a separator, and matches on string, so `urn:`, `urn:myscheme` and `urn:myscheme:foo:bar:12345` can only be represented as completely different paths.

The guts of it happens in [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7):

```
$original_map = arg(NULL, $path);

$parts = array_slice($original_map, 0, MENU_MAX_PARTS);
$ancestors = menu_get_ancestors($parts);
$router_item = db_query_range('SELECT * FROM {menu_router} WHERE path IN (:ancestors) ORDER BY fit DESC', 0, 1, array(':ancestors' => $ancestors))->fetchAssoc();
```

The call to `arg()` splits the path by `/`, which is hardcoded:

```
$arguments[$path] = explode('/', $path);
```

When [`menu_get_ancestors()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_ancestors/7) returns for a path like `urn/myscheme`, it has two elements in the array: 'urn' and 'myscheme'. The same call for `urn:myscheme` returns an array with a single element, 'urn:myscheme'.

Those ancestors are used directly in the query to match the path in `menu_router`, so for the path `urn:myscheme`, you'll get this query:

```
SELECT * FROM {menu_router} WHERE path IN ('urn:myscheme') ORDER BY fit DESC
```

Try the same thing with `urn:myscheme:foo:bar:12345`, and as far as Drupal's concerned, it's a separate path that has to be handled by a different router item, as the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM {menu_router} WHERE path IN ('urn:myscheme:foo:bar:12345') ORDER BY fit DESC
```

Without resorting to replacing menu.inc (which I think is pluggable if I remember rightly), `hook_url_inbound_alter()` will probably be the best best.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to be wrong with this.  hook_url_inbound_alter() is a little sub-optimal, because I get a 301 (I think b/c Global Redirect).  The exact situation is way more complicated than the question suggests...

Comment: Ain't it always :) I can think of a couple-of-lines solution but it would mean patching core. You could add logic to `arg()` to also split on the `:` character, which would let you use `urn:%scheme:%foo:%bar:%id` for example. I don't even think there would be any site-wide negative effects from doing that (unless there are paths defined by other modules with `:` in them, then it'll all go mental). Patching core is never great though